# obs-studio build fails on Raspbain Buster

Tags: raspbian-buster, obs-studio, pipewire

I am using Raspbian buster `5.10.52-v7l+` on Raspberry pi 4B 8GB.

Building obs-studio fails with:
`CMake` Error at `plugins/linux-capture/CMakeLists.txt:53 (message): PipeWire library not found! Please install PipeWire or set ENABLE_PIPEWIRE=OFF`

Raspbian Buster has pipewire version is 0.2.5-1 installed The bbs-studio build fails needs pipewire0.3.

Building pipewire from source fails

`/spa/plugins/libcamera/libcamera_wrapper.cpp:52:10: fatal error: libcamera/framebuffer.h: No such file or directory #include <libcamera/framebuffer.h>`

Are there any solutions.  upgrade OS version.  Change OS?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add following arguments to your cmake command:

`-DENABLE_WAYLAND=OFF -DENABLE_PIPEWIRE=OFF`

**This will only work if you are not using wayland**